# Can に対して be replaced with に比べて sometimes?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Can に対して be replaced with に比べて sometimes?

For comparing things. Taishite seems to have other comparison uses that are more specific but kurabete seems more flexible for general comparison use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prescriptively speaking, no, but descriptively speaking, yes.  It happens **informally/colloquially and in certain contexts**.

So, in what contexts?  That is when 「～～に対{たい}して」 is used to describe a ***contrast*** between two (or more) facts/things.  When it means "***towards***", however, it could never be replaced by 「～～に比{くら}べて」.

Examples:

You would see/hear:

> 「日本人男性{にほんじんだんせい}の平均靴{へいきんくつ}サイズが25センチであるの**に比べて**、オランダ人男性のそれは29センチである。」
>
> "The average shoe size for Japanese men is 25cm.  In contrast with that, that for Dutch men is 29cm."

Grammarians might prefer seeing/hearing 「に対して」 there instead, but who speaks to please grammarians in his daily conversations?

You would ***not*** see/hear:

> 「あの先生{せんせい}は学生{がくせい}**に比べて**とても厳{きび}しい。」
>
> "That teacher is very strict with his students."

That sentence is just out of the question.  You must use 「に対して」 there.